# Is there some extra settings for bloom pass in 3.2 beta?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, render-passes

In v3.1.2, the bloom pass:[image: bloom pass in v3.1.2]

but, in v3.2 the bloom pass output is same as the default combined output:[image: bloom pass in v3.2 beta]

Is there some extra settings for bloom pass in v3.2 beta?

Comment: A quick Google search brings up a new [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_6jxktV_BY) about Light Groups so it's possible bloom is now controlled there.

Comment: my wild guess is: it's a beta software, the bloom pass is messed up in the current build.

Comment: @JohnEason I've watched that video about Light Groups yesterday, but light groups is only for cycles, the bloom pass is only for eevee

Comment: @L0Lock Yah,it's a bug maybe,but I even tried v3.3, still not working

Comment: Ah ok. Apologies.

Comment: But 3.3 is in alpha. It you are this concerned about it, look at the bug tracker if there's anyone mentioning this issue, or post a bug report